# mobile app browsers audio recorder high frequencies

Tags: javascript, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

in chrome PC i can record high frequencies , but in mobile chrome app or any other browser mobile app high frequencies are cutting off . any idea?

i have tried to create high pass filter  with `createBiquadFilter` , did not work .

i am using Audio Context.

```
 const filterNode =  this.context.createBiquadFilter(); 
    const source = this.context.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);


    const processor = this.context.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
    source.connect(processor);
    // filterNode.connect(processor);
    // processor.connect(filterNode)

    // source.connect(processor);
    // processor.connect(this.context.destination);

    processor.connect(this.context.destination);


    // filterNode.type="highpass";
    // filterNode.frequency.value = 17000;
    // filterNode.gain.value=25;

    let int32 = new Int32Array(4096);
    processor.onaudioprocess = async function(e) {}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean with "did not work". Was there any error message? If there is any, it would certainly help if you could provide it.

Comment: No errors , server side recieved the audio buffer, but not the high frequencies